# bad operand types for binary operator '+' for tostring return

Tags: java, binary, operator-keyword, operand

Link to a screenshot of the code to the account class. I am trying to return the values in the toString but I do not know why this error occurs. I have tried to manually convert them into strings but to no avail. I am running out of ideas

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMIvt.jpg

Comment: What do you think using the `+` operator with a `Date`, an `int`, a `Customer`, and a `double` should do? Why do you think so?

Comment: Instead of linking an image of your code, please copy and paste the code into your question, and use the `{}` button to format it as code.

Answer (score 2):

The operands you're adding are not Strings. You need to convert them somehow, like `String.valueOf(accountNumber) + String.valueOf(dateOpened) + ...`.

Comment: You really only need to do it on the first one. The rest will automatically become string concatenations, because `+` is left-to-right.